# Contour Plot of planetary motion in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, physics

I was trying to make the contour plot on $(v,r)$ axis for planetary motion for different orbits to check for bounded and unbounded motion. 
This is what I tried

```
ContourPlot[0.5` 
   Derivative[1][r][t]^2 - 0.2`/r[t] + 0.6`/r[t]^2 == k, {k, -10,10}, 
      {Derivative[1][r][t], 0, 100}, {r[t], -5, 5}]
```

This is what I get as an error

> Options expected (instead of {r[t],-5,5}) beyond position 3

I can't figure out what's wrong with that.

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica* SE! Please, compare your code the examples of `ContourPlot` in the documenation. The thrid arguments needs to be a range specification similar to the second. The equation in the first argument needs to be solved, and depend only on `k` and `t`.

Comment: @Johu I looked on ContourPlot documentation. I could not find a Contour example of a function and its derivative. `r[t] and r'[t]` in my case. Or should I explicitly write equations of `r[t] and r'[t]` and solve them ?

Comment: Yes, you have to solve the equation before. Look up `DSolve`.

Comment: @Johu Actually I managed to get it. I changed $r'[t]$ to $v[t]$ and removed k and addded an extra argument in the end `{Contours -> 10}` and voila I got it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, You are right. This works, because the plotted function is then only a function of $v$ and $r$. Consider answering your own qustion with the solution you found, such that others could later learn from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ContourPlot[0.5` v[t]^2 - 2/r[t] + 6/r[t]^2,
  {r[t], 0, 100}, 
  {v[t], -0.5, 0.5}, 
  Contours -> 10, ContourShading -> None, ContourLabels -> All
]
```

[image]

This gives 10 Contours There is no Shading to distinguish them because I want it like that and I have labeled the Contours too for easier identification.

Comment: I hope you do not mind, that I edited the code for the readability, replaced `none` with `None` and added the output figure. Keep it up learning *Mathematica*!

Comment: No not at all. I was infact trying to add an image but didn't want to take a screenshot of it

Comment: They are very easy to import. I select the figure in the notebook, click shortcut keys for `edit->copy as->bitmap` and paste it into import figure dialog box of the form.

Comment: Alright. I'll do that next time